# Python can't import config from config file using trading_ig API

Tags: python, eclipse, macos, trading

i have the following python issue in Eclipse on a Mac.
I want to use the trading_ig API from IG.com. The library is succesfully installed. When i run the following code part from the example provided on this website (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trading_ig/0.0.3):

```
import trading_ig
from trading_ig import IGService
from trading_ig.config import config
```

i get the error:

> can't import config from config file
>   DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.ig.com
>   DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://api.ig.com:443 "POST >/gateway/deal/session HTTP/1.1" 200 308
>   DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://api.ig.com:443 "GET >/gateway/deal/accounts HTTP/1.1" 200 196
>   accounts:
>    accountAlias accountId accountName accountType  canTransferFrom  \
>   0         None     GYRFL         CFD         CFD             True
>
> canTransferTo currency  preferred                  status  available  \
>   0           True      EUR       True  SUSPENDED_FROM_DEALING        0.0
>
> balance  deposit  profitLoss
>   0      0.0      0.0         0.0
>
> DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://api.ig.com:443 "GET >/gateway/deal/prices/IX.D.ASX.IFM.IP/DAY/10 HTTP/1.1" 200 605

Using this code i can get response from the http but i still need to get the config working. Since i'm new to python i have been searching for solutions but could not find one. Help is appreciated.

Comment: That's because you have replaced the underscore with a dot - last line should be `from trading_ig_config import config`.

Comment: Thanks got it working now.